# Selecting records which appear more then once, under some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table has three columns:

- First column represent the two letter shortcuts for country names (AF for Afghanistan, AL for Albania etc.)
- in the second column is date
- the third column can only have values `0` or `1`

In the 1st column there can be more then one country and they are always separated by comma followed by space.

My job is to fire an warning if one country is on the both lists for one date (more precisely, if one country has value `0` and value `1` in the third column, on same date).

How could I do that?

Next table represents the situation in which I should fire a warning (because of `AF`):

```
+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|  Country list   |    Date     | True/False |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| AF, AL, DE, MA  | 20.06.2018. |          1 |
| LC, KN, AF      | 20.06.2018. |          0 |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: You can start by changing your table structure to a normalized one by spliting the country. Then it would be as simple as a `group by country, date having count(distinct [true/false]) > 1`.

Comment: That's not an option, because I am not the owner of the table. The table does not really look like this. It has more columns, and is more populated. The third column represents if it is a holiday for some country on the selected date.

Comment: The solution still applies, use a string split function on the country list (thousands of examples online) then do the mentioned group by. You can perfrom this on the same statement, no need to change the definition of your table.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm gonna try that!

Comment: Do you have a separate list of countries?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I do. Here is what I did:
`SELECT Date, isnull([Country List],'') Country List, [true/false] FROM TABLE WHERE DATUM='20.06.2018.' AND CHARINDEX('here I am putting first two letters from list Gordon mentioned',Country List)<>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a split function, for example use this (more info [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Now you can split the country list and `group by` on the country code to find the codes that appear more than once (I added another date `22.06.2018.` to have a more complete example):

```
declare @tmp table([CountryList] varchar(max), [Date] varchar(20), TrueFalse bit)

insert into @tmp values
('AF, AL, DE, MA','20.06.2018.',   1),
('LC, KN, AF','20.06.2018.',       0),
('AF, AL, DE, MA','22.06.2018.',   1),
('LC, KN, AF','22.06.2018.',       0)

SELECT  [Date], value as country, count(distinct [TrueFalse])
FROM @tmp   
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace([CountryList],', ','|'), '|')
        group by value, [Date]
```

Results:

[image]

Now you can filter the results to find out multiple codes:

```
SELECT  [Date], value as country, count(distinct [TrueFalse])
FROM @tmp   
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace([CountryList],', ','|'), '|')
        group by value, [Date]
        having count(distinct [TrueFalse]) > 1
```

Results:

[image]

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use the new `STRING_SPLIT` function without using a custom split function:

```
SELECT  [Date], splitdata  as country, count(distinct [TrueFalse])
FROM @tmp   
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fnSplitString](replace([CountryList],', ','|'), '|')
        group by splitdata, [Date]
        having count(distinct [TrueFalse]) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not create a function try this:

```
WITH tTable --Your table
AS (SELECT [CountryList], [Date], TrueFalse
      FROM ( VALUES ('AF, AL, DE, MA', '2018-20-06', 1)
                  , ('LC, KN, AF'    , '2018-20-06', 0)
                  , ('AF, AL, DE, MA', '2018-21-06', 1)
                  , ('LC, KN, AF'    , '2018-21-06', 0)
           ) tTable([CountryList], [Date], TrueFalse)
   )
, tTableRecursive 
    AS( SELECT nCharIndex  = CHARINDEX(',', [CountryList]) -- Find Comma
                           -- Find first country
             , Country     = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [CountryList]) = 0 
                                  THEN [CountryList]
                                  ELSE SUBSTRING ([CountryList], 0, CHARINDEX(',', [CountryList]))

                             END
                             --List without first country
             , CountryList = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [CountryList]) = 0 
                                  THEN ''
                                  ELSE SUBSTRING ([CountryList], CHARINDEX(',', [CountryList])   + 1   , 500)
                             END
             , [Date]
             , TrueFalse
          FROM tTable tTable

         UNION ALL

        SELECT nCharIndex  = CHARINDEX(',', CountryList, 0)
                           -- Recursive Get Next Country
             , Country     = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', CountryList, 0) = 0 
                                  THEN CountryList
                                  ELSE SUBSTRING (CountryList, 0, CHARINDEX(',', CountryList))
                             END
                             -- Remove country of list
             , CountryList = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', CountryList, 0) > 0 
                                  THEN SUBSTRING (CountryList   , CHARINDEX(',', CountryList)    + 1 , 500)
                                  ELSE ''
                             END
             , [Date]
             , TrueFalse
          FROM tTableRecursive tTableRecursive
         WHERE tTableRecursive.nCharIndex > 0
)

, tResult 
    AS ( SELECT Country = LTRIM(Country)
              , [Date]            
           FROM tTableRecursive    
          GROUP BY LTRIM(Country) 
               , [Date]     
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TrueFalse) > 1
       )

SELECT Country 
     , [Date]
  FROM tResult
```